# Calling MVC HttpPost method (with Parameter) using HttpwebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest

I have the following MVC method.

```
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Listen(string status)
    {

        CFStatusMessage statusMessage = new CFStatusMessage();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(status))
        {
            statusMessage = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CFStatusMessage>(status);
        }
        return Content(Server.HtmlEncode(status));// View(statusMessage);
    }
```

I am trying to call the above method from Other application .. (Console). I am using HttpWebRequest to make a call to the MVC Method. Using the below code its able to call the method but the Parameter is always coming as empty string.

```
        string content = "{\"status\":\"success\",\"payload\":\"some information\"}";
        string url = "http://myrl.com";
        var httpWRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
        var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(string.Format("status={0}", Uri.EscapeDataString(content)));
        httpWRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

        Stream stream = httpWRequest.GetRequestStream();
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWRequest.GetResponse();
```

With this its making a call to Listen method but status parameter is always coming blank. whereas I want the json string {status:"success",payload:"some information"} as parameter.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S.: I tried the below statement as well, while sending the actual content.

```
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(content);
```

Regards,
M

Comment: Habe you checked with fiddler, how your request looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If do you need to provide any kind of service from MVC tryout WebApi instead. You can use HTTP  REST to do this easily.

Read more here [ASP.NET WebApi](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-web-api)

Comment: Hi Fals,   I got one more problem. Now, I am using ApiController of MVC 4.0. If the method signature is "public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]CustomMessage msg)" and I send Json string as mentioned above it works. But If I want to get string i.e. "public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string msg)", the msg param is blank.... Any ways to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be saying the request is json, but sending it using wwwencoding.

Remove the `status={0}` line bit & just send the json as is.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(httpWRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    sw.Write(content);
    sw.Flush();
    sw.Close();
}
```